# ubuntuを外部ストレージにインストール後に表示されるようになったgrubコンソール画面を出ないようにしたい

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub

初書き込みです、よろしくお願いいたします。

普段使用しているWindowsPCを使用してUSB-C接続の外部SSDへUbuntuをインストールしました。
その後より端末起動時に
①Ubuntu=USB-Cを接続しているときはgrubのOS選択画面が
➁Ubuntu=USB-Cを接続していないときには"Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported....."と言った文言とともにgrubコンソール画面が表示されるようになりました。

①の場合は選択したOSがそれぞれ起動するので良いのですが
➁の場合はgrubコンソールにて二回exitと入力することでwindowsが起動する事になっており、少々手間です。

やりたいことは➁のUSB-C接続していないときにgrubコンソール画面を表示させずにいままで通りにwindowsの起動をさせたいと思っています。

色々とgrub周りの情報を調べたのですが、解決策が見当たらず。
/etc/default/grubの設定でどうにかなるのでしょうか？
お教え頂ければ幸いです。

追記
ありがとうざございます。
コメントで結果を上手く表示できないのでこちらで表記します。

```
hajime@hajime-MB-K690:~$ sudo cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg
[sudo] hajime のパスワード: 
search.fs_uuid aebf0b9e-caff-497c-adf4-3b35ee4d5620 root hd1,gpt1 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

そして/boot/grub/grub.cfgのmenuentryがこちらです。

```
hajime@hajime-MB-K690:~$ grep -e "^\(menuentry\)\|\(submenu\)" /boot/grub/grub.cfg
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-aebf0b9e-caff-497c-adf4-3b35ee4d5620' {
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-aebf0b9e-caff-497c-adf4-3b35ee4d5620' {
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/nvme0n1p2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-2C18-BC38' {
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
```

Comment: Ubuntuインストールの際に GRUBもインストールしたものと思われます。GRUBのインストール先や grub.cfgの位置が問題かも。Ubuntuで `sudo cat /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grub.cfg` すると何が出ますか？ /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 などの UUID指してるか確認できますか？

Comment: さっそくのコメントありがとうございます。コマンド結果をコメントでは上手く表示させることができないので質問文に貼り付けさせてもらいました。UUIDはUbuntuのIDを指しているようです。こちらをWindows Boot ManagerのIDへ変更すれば良いのでしょうか？

Comment: `ls /dev/disk/by-uuid/ -l` などでディスクの UUID見れます。`configfile $prefix/grub.cfg` により USBにある grub.cfg探して, 接続されてないから grub-shellに移るのでしょう(たぶん)。Windowsのディスクの UUIDに変更する場合, 指定の場所に `grub.cfg` が存在するのかどうかが問題。と, 存在しないのならどんな内容にすればいいか …

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。Windowsディスクの指定場所のgrub.cfgを探してみます。本日はもう遅いので明日やってみます。すみません、、、

Comment: ふと思ったのですがusbを外している状態での起動でgrubが立ち上がるという事はwindowsのディスク上にgrubがインストールされているという事ですよね？ubuntuインストール時にブートローダーのインストール先は外部ssdを指定しましたがwindowsディスクにインストールされたのですかね？しかしそのgrubのconfigfileは外部ssdから読み込まれるように設定されているようです。このconfigfileをwindowsディスク上から読み込まれるようにすれば良いのかと思っておりましたが。なんと本日のwindowsアップデートしたところ問題が解決してしまいました。具体的には外部ssdを外している状態で起動するとwindowsが起動、usbから起動するとgrubのOS選択画面が出るようになりました。やりたい事がなぜかできるようになりましたなんだかよく分からない解決となり、申し訳ありません、、、。これは解決とは言いませんね

Comment: それぞれのディスクに それぞれの UEFIパーティションがあり, それらのどこかに齟齬があるのかと考えてました … が, 「updateで直った」って回答になるのかな？